# nikto for window (error : unable to connect to host )

Tags: windows

I want to install nikto on window

I follow the steps that notice at nikto githup.

1. install perl
2. download zip file and install it
3. USE "perl nikto.pl -h http://www.example.com" command , but it occurs error like this.

C:\Users\username\Desktop\test\tool\nikto\nikto-master\nikto-master\program>perl ./nikto.pl -h 192.168.0.174
Locale 'Korean_Korea.949' is unsupported, and may crash the interpreter.

- Nikto v2.5.0

---

---

- Unable to connect to 192.168.0.174:80.
- 0 host(s) tested

but when I test in kali, it works.

└─# nikto -h 192.168.0.174

- Nikto v2.5.0

---

- Target IP:          192.168.0.174
- Target Hostname:    192.168.0.174
- Target Port:        80
- Start Time:         2024-03-22 11:43:46 (GMT0)

---

- Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Debian)
- /: The anti-clickjacking X-Frame-Options header is not present. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

I don't know why it doesn't work on windows. help me,,,

solve the problems please,,,